# Are there Google App Engine source and JavaDoc JAR bundles available?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I noticed that well-known Maven repositories don't provide Google App Engine service Java source JARs or Javadoc JARs. E.g., http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1636166512 only provides class JARs.

For comparison, log4j provides both source and Javadoc JARs to class JARs; that is, at http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1442692743 , `log4j-1.2.16.jar` is accompanied by `log4j-1.2.16-sources.jar` and `log4j-1.2.16-javadoc.jar`

Are such source/Javadoc JARs available for GAE Java modules?

The (unbundled) source code is available at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src .

Answer (score 2):

Download the Java SDK from the appropriate GAE page. From within this .jar file, I use the following files/folders:

Source files:

```
src\orm\*.zip
```

Javadoc files:

```
docs
```

The "read me" file in the SDK gives full details of the meaning of the folders in the SDK.

Enjoy?

Comment: The SDK only includes Datanucleus and JDO2 sources. 

I'm looking for other GAE-specific sources as well, for instance for com.google.appengine.api.users.User .

Of course I can checkout the sources from the SVN repository, then attach the whole repository folder for source access from within Eclipse... but a JAR bundle would be more comfortable.

Comment: @Abdull Good point: I never paid much attention to what was in my GAE sources.

Comment: The current appengine download seems to contain most of the source code eg. `appengine-java-sdk-1.9.46/src/user/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.46-src.zip`

Answer (score 1):

There is now a source .zip file at the original location you gave
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/appengine-api-src.zip

So whilst it's not quite as easy in eclipse as "Maven>Download Sources", you can at least now  put that somewhere local, "Properties>Java Source Attachment" on the .jar in your project and set the location of that .zip file.  This gets you the source from which eclipse will display the javadoc also.

Comment: Google closed that source hosting. Looks like they don't want to provide sources anymore.

Comment: The current appengine download seems to contain most of the source code. Ian Marshall's answer is now correct again.